# Filling a UIPickerView from a feed

Tags: iphone, ios, rss, uipickerview

I'm parsing a feed of location into an `NSMutableArray` called items. I am filling the a `UIPickerView` as follows:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView {
return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component {
return [items count];
}

- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row     forComponent:(NSInteger)component {
return [items objectAtIndex:row];
}

-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row
  inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
id item = [items objectAtIndex:row];
NSString *occasion = [item objectForKey:@"name"];
location.text = occasion;
}
```

When I do this no values are appearing in the UIPickerView, can someone help me with this please? Everything is connected correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:    (NSInteger)component {
return [items count];
}

- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row     forComponent:(NSInteger)component {
id item = [items objectAtIndex:row];
NSString *occasion = [item objectForKey:@"name"];
return occasion;
}

-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row
  inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
id item = [items objectAtIndex:row];
NSString *occasion = [item objectForKey:@"name"];
location.text = occasion;
}
```

this will display string in picker

also set delegate of pickerview

i think you are passing whole dictionaty instead of string may be

Comment: By doing this I get the following error *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'request for rect at invalid index path (<NSIndexPath 0x200a28c0> 2 indexes [0, 0])'

Comment: you are passing dictionary i think so try passing NSString Object

Comment: can you giving me some directions for doing this please, I really appreciate it

Comment: please copy paste my code which i have post i think this will solve it and check your pickerview delegate is set to self

Answer (score 1):

Do these things:

#1 Make sure you set the delegate properly. Eg. :

```
self.pickerView.delegate = self;
```

#2 Check if your occasion string is not nil nor empty.

```
NSLog(@"%@", occasion);
```

Comment: the delegate is set correctly and the array isn't empty Array: (
    Manchester,
    Huddersfield,
    Elland,
    Yeovil,
    London
)

Comment: Your array is not empty but you retrieve your data with `[item objectForKey:@"name"]` method. Check if the returned value is not empty.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing items array can be dictionary array. So, you should get the NSString inside NSDictionary.

```
- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row     forComponent:(NSInteger)component {
return [[items objectForKey:@"name"] objectAtIndex:row];
}
```